# find eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose
$$
A=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1},
C=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1}
$$
and we know that $B$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix with eigenvalues  $0,\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$. Can we find the eigenvalues of the matrix $P = ABC$?

Comment: Hello, please see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) about how to format mathematical expressions on this site.

Comment: Is $B$ just an arbitrary matrix or the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A/C$

Comment: B is just a random matrix with eigenvalues $0, \lambda_1, \lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$.

Answer (score 1):

No. E.g. $B_1=\operatorname{diag}(0,1,2,3)$ and $B_2=\operatorname{diag}(3,2,1,0)$ have the same eigenvalues, but $AB_1C=\operatorname{diag}(\frac12,2,3)$ and $AB_2C=\operatorname{diag}(\frac52,1,0)$ have entirely different eigenvalues.